# Como pasar datos de un listview a otros listview de otra actividad

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, adapter

Tengo un problema y es que tengo una App donde ya hay registrado datos de firebase realtime, que son datos de libros con imagen, y estoy intentando pasar esos datos de ese listview a otro listview en otra actividad. Lo que quiero es que esos datos se muestren en la otra actividad incluyendose en el firebase con otro child. En la lista principal uso un alertDialog para 3 opciones, una es mostrarme otro activity donde se ven los detalles y resumen del libro, otro que es para alquilar el cual me lleva al activity "mi cuenta" que es donde quiero almacenar esos datos del libro concreto que yo elijo, y otra opcion que simplemente no hace nada, es un cancelar. Dejo aquí el código de la actividad donde se muestran los datos de libros en la lista principal.

```java
package com.project.renbooks;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ListaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lista;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    ImageView portada;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Libros");
        lista = findViewById(R.id.lvLista);

        leerDatosLista();
    }

    private void leerDatosLista() {

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Libros");
        FirebaseListOptions<Libros> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Libros>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.libros)
                .setQuery(query, Libros.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {

            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                TextView titulo = v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
                TextView editorial = v.findViewById(R.id.tvEditorial);
                TextView autor = v.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);
                TextView paginas = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPaginas);
                TextView isbn = v.findViewById(R.id.tvISBN);
                portada = v.findViewById(R.id.ivImagenDetalles);
                TextView resumen = v.findViewById(R.id.tvresumen);

                final Libros libros = (Libros) model;
                titulo.setText(libros.getTitulo());
                editorial.setText("Editorial: " + libros.getEditorial());
                autor.setText("Autor: " + libros.getAutor());
                paginas.setText("Páginas: " + libros.getPaginas());
                isbn.setText("ISBN: " + libros.getIsbn());
                Picasso.with(ListaActivity.this).load((libros.getPortada())).into(portada);
                resumen.setText(libros.getResumen());

                portada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent visorImagen = new Intent(v.getContext(), VisorImagen.class);
                        visorImagen.putExtra("POR", libros.getPortada());
                        startActivity(visorImagen);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListaActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Renbooks")
                        .setMessage("¿Que desea hacer?")
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.stringAlquilar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Intent visorAlquilarLibro = new Intent(view.getContext(), MiCuentaActivity.class);
                                Libros libros = (Libros) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                visorAlquilarLibro.putExtra("IMG", libros.getPortada());
                                visorAlquilarLibro.putExtra("TIT", libros.getTitulo());
                                visorAlquilarLibro.putExtra("EDI", libros.getEditorial());
                                visorAlquilarLibro.putExtra("AUT", libros.getAutor());
                                visorAlquilarLibro.putExtra("PAG", libros.getPaginas());
                                visorAlquilarLibro.putExtra("ISB", libros.getIsbn());
                                startActivity(visorAlquilarLibro);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.stringInfo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Intent visorDetallesLibros = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetallesLibros.class);
                                Libros libros = (Libros) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                visorDetallesLibros.putExtra("IMG", libros.getPortada());
                                visorDetallesLibros.putExtra("TIT", libros.getTitulo());
                                visorDetallesLibros.putExtra("DET", libros.getResumen());
                                startActivity(visorDetallesLibros);

                            }
                        })

                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.stringAtras, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.miCuenta:
                startActivity(new Intent(ListaActivity.this,MiCuentaActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.miAbout:
                startActivity(new Intent(ListaActivity.this,AcercaDe.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.miSalir:
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No tengo muy claro el problema pero si tienes datos en la lista de la ActivityA y quires esos mismos datos en la ActivityB, las opciones son: a) pasarlos por Bundle si es menos de 1MB, b) que la ActivityB vuelva a pedir los datos a Firebase o c) Crear una caché con los datos de la lista que descargas la primera vez.

Comment: Buenas Manuel gracias por responder, verás el caso es que en la ActivityA tengo una lista de libros, donde obtengo los datos de firebase (Los agrego desde Firebase) y esa lista tiene un selector de items, es decir yo clickeo en un item de esa lista (Un libro) y me salta un mensaje donde puedo ver la info (Me manda a otro activity donde veo el resumen de dicho libro) o bien puedo alquilar libro (Que es la parte que me falta) y la idea es que al pulsar alquilar libro, me recoja esos datos concretos (El libro) y que me lo mande a la otra lista como si el usuario hubiese alquilado el libro

Comment: Entonces, en la ActivityB se muestra una lista de los libros alquilados.  En este caso, la lógica es que al pulsar en el libro de la ActivityA, se guarde en tu Firebase y navegar a la ActivityB, la cuál debe refrescar la lista, es decir, volver a solicitar esos datos a Firebase... Para que el usuario no espere, yo guardaría el libro desde la ActivityA, lo pasaría por Bundle y lo añadiría a la lista y, si se ha guardado en la nube correctamente no hago nada pero si no se ha guardado, borro el libro y muestro un mensaje indicando que ha habido un error con la opción de volverlo a alquilar.

Comment: Hola Manuel, al final he decidido cambiar el modo de hacerlo, ya que me he dado cuenta que en mi App el usuario solo puede alquilar un libro, y hasta que no lo devuelva no puede alquilar otro, asi que he decidido que en la activityB no tenga lista, solo los datos y un boton de devolver, muchas gracias por la ayuda, un saludo!